# Django and wkhtmltopdf working fine from Python shell but not from URL

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

```
call([WKHTMLTOPDF_COMMAND_PATH, html_file_url, pdf_file_path])
```

The above command generates pdf in the specified location when run from python shell. But when from URL, gets stuck as show below

```
Loading pages (1/6)            10%
```

Comment: "Loading pages (1/6) 10%" <- What's this?

Comment: After loading 10% it gets stuck.. "Loading pages (1/6) 10%" actually signifies that 10% of the pdf has been generated.

Comment: Is this a browser's progress bar or else?

Comment: Nope it comes in the console